# Applying SSL in tomcat doesn't work with ip address

Tags: ssl, https, port, tomcat8

I'm using Tomcat 8.5.73 v

On tomcat,

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" connectionTimeout="999999" port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="E:/OpenSSL/key/test2/private.key" certificateFile="E:/OpenSSL/key/test2/certificate.crt" certificateChainFile="E:/OpenSSL/key/test2/ca_bundle.crt" type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

I wrote above code on server.xml and

this code in web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>HTTP</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
    <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

Redirecting is perfectly working and I thought there was no problem.

When I enter in http://localhost:8080 or https://localhost:8443, it works perfectly.

However, when I enter in http://myip(192.xxx.xx.xx):8080, it work when https://myip(192.xxx.xx.xx):8443 doesn't work with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

P.S. I added in-bound rule in firewall with 443/8443 port

Comment: HTTPS links with IP addresses instead of hostnames are a bad idea in general. It can work, as you can have IP addresses in certificates, but is in general more a problem than a solution. So try to stick to names.

Comment: I got a domain for those IPs, which is xxx.xxxxxxxx.kro.kr.
I got SSL Certificates for this domain and tried port 8080 and it works perfectly 
and works on https://localhost:8443 which is not working on https://domain:8443...